How to get windows's handle in windows Avalonia UI?
I want get the handle of window that created by Avalonia UI on Windows platform.
In WPF,it coded with:
new WindowInteropHelper(MainWindow.instance).Handle
But I did't get any interface that allows me get the handle of window directly.
I tried this but the complier told me that member donsn't exists.
I've using lasted version of Avalonia UI.
But that Avalonia.Win32.WindowImpl has some protection level so i can't convert the MainWindow.PlatformImpl to Avalonia.Win32.WindowImpl.
Is there any way to get handle of window by original Avalonia UI?

You'll need to cast MainWindow.PlatformImpl to your required native type, something like Avalonia.Win32.WindowImpl or Avalonia.X11.X11Window depending on the platform you've targeting/ currently running on.

The question is i can't cast that to native type...

Use the TryGetPlatformHandle method of the TopLevel class, a base class of Window:
IntPtr? handle = window.TryGetPlatformHandle()?.Handle;


Thanks! Your answer is currently work in my program.
